# Returning specific object from Python API call

Tags: python, json, powershell, api

I do the majority of my automation work in PowerShell and I would like to start using Python but running into some issues with the json module.

In PowerShell, lets say I write a basic function to return a list of users from a random API

```
Function Get-APIUser {
   # Set URI    
   $Uri = "https://api.app.com/v1/users.json"
   # Set Headers
   $Headers = @{'Api-Key'='Insert Key Here'}
   # Call API
   $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -Method GET
   # Output Results
   $Response.links
}
```

I call this function to return a specific user and store the returned object as a variable

```
$User = Get-APIUser | Where-Object {$_.email -eq "Insert User Email Here"}
```

Now all the information of that specific object is stored as a key value pair in the variable

```
id            : 123456789
email         : email@email.com
firstName     : John
lastName      : Smith
accountStatus : active
```

You can the call that variable `$User` and pull from specific key value pairs. For example

```
If ($User.accountStatus -ne "active") {
    Try {
        # Do something
    }
    Catch {
    }      
}
```

Python

```
import requests
import json

def get_apiuser():
    uri = 'https://api.app.com/v1/users.json'
    headers = {'Api-Key':'Insert Key Here'}

    try:
        response = requests.get(uri,headers=headers)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        print(error)
    
    jsonData = json.dumps(response)
    print(jsonData)
```

How would I got about returning just the data under `links ($Response.links)` like I specified in the PowerShell function. Also how would I sort through the results and store a user, for example, as a variable for later reuse?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to `dumps` (which would dump a Python object or dictionary into a json string), you want `loads`, which loads a python object from a json string, which is what is retrieved by the get request. Something like `data = json.loads(response.text)`. If you do, you can access the elements you need like you would any Python dictionary, i.e. something like `data['links']`.